# How calculate position with event.nativeEvent.layout when is inside a view

Tags: react-native

I am trying to do a drag and drop component and for that I need x and y position of the dropZone. all is fine but when i try to get the area and the position of my dropzone When is inside a view react-native give to me a value based in the view, can i know the root position in some way.

> whit onLayout i take the event

```
<View style={styles.borderView}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>
    after he had dug down only a few inches he uncovered a 
    <View
      onLayout={this.setDropZoneValues.bind(this)}
      style={styles.viewDropZone}
    >
      <Text>_________</Text>
    </View>
    of silver coins and jewelry. He couldn’t believe it
  </Text>
</View>
```

> here I take the area, y and x

```
setDropZoneValues(event) {
        this.props.setDropZoneValue(event.nativeEvent.layout);
}
```

> styles

```
viewDropZone: {
    backgroundColor:'red',
    height: 10,
    width: 60
},
text: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.transparent,
    textAlign: 'left',
},
borderView: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.colomboGrayBackground,
    marginTop: 5,
    margin: 8,
    padding: 10,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: theme.colors.colomboSubTitle,
},
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handled that issue

I used onLayaut in both the parent view and the Son View, in the parent I saved the value in a state and when I calculated the position in the son View  I added the parentPosition to my postionValue in my View.

some code:

> parent

```
    renderSection(seccion, key) {
    return (
        <View onLayout={(event) => this.props.setSeccionOffset(event.nativeEvent.layout.y, seccion.id)} style={styles.mainContainer} key={key}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title} >{seccion.title}</Text>
            {seccion.questions.map((dropZones, idx) => {
                return this.renderDropZones(dropZones, idx, seccion.id)
            })}
        </View>
    )
}
```

> son

```
    renderDropZones(seccion, idx, parentId) {
    return (
        <View onLayout={(event) => this.setDropZoneValues(event, seccion, parentId)} style={styles.leftField} key={idx}>
            <Text style={styles.LabelTittle} numberOfLines={1}> {seccion.text} <Text style={[styles.LabelTittle, { color: this.setColor() }]}>{seccion.selectedBy}</Text></Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

> here i calculated the position of my view based in his parent and the parent postion based in the screen

```
    setDropZoneValues(event, seccion, parentId) {
    let dropZone = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            dropZone.id = seccion.index;
            dropZone.y += this.props.multiDragStore.seccions[parentId].offsetContainer;
            this.props.setDropZoneValue(dropZone);
        },
        10,
        dropZone
    );
}
```

the setTimeOut is because onlayout is a callback and i need validate that the offset of his parent was defined before i calculate the son position